# Having a hard time writing a midi melody in my DAW

Tags: melody

I have a problem. I am writing a midi melody in a part of a song in Reaper.

I'm having a hard time writing it because several notes sound out of beat and I have no reference (bar lines) so, being a repetitive melody, when I start a new bar I might unintentionally place a note a little bit before or after and the melody loses its rhythm.

Is there anything I can do to help me in this situation? My knowledge of harmony is very basic, the signature time of the song is 4/4 and I think that in this case I am putting about 11 notes per bar.

Comment: Can you turn a metronome on?

Comment: There should be grid lines in the piano roll view. Also there is probably a snap function and/or quantize to help you get notes right on the beat.

Comment: This seems like one of those questions we'd need to be looking over your shoulder to see what's going on. As we can't see that far, we *really* need a better explanation. How are you 'writing' it? Clicking notes in, playing it live…" If you have no reference, what is driving your tempo? [Plus the 11 notes in a bar bit, which feels more like a quantity than a quality].

Comment: Do you intend to put 11 notes in a bar, or something more like 8 or 12?

Answer (score 1):

There are technology issues and music theory issues to solve here. I'm unfamiliar with Reaper, so let's address the music theory ones first. You say you have "about 11 notes per bar"; are these notes all the same length? That would be surprising—but not unheard of—since 4/4 could divide evenly into 12 notes, but 11 would not line up with the beats that are inside the bar. If you're not sure, hum your melody carefully to yourself and think: are any of the notes longer or shorter than others? How do they line up with beats? If you tap your foot (or turn on a metronome) to mark the beat, which notes start at the same moment that a beat starts? If it turns out that the notes are of different lengths, you might have to figure out how to represent their different lengths in notation.

But how are you interacting with the DAW? Looking at [the Reaper user guide](https://dlz.reaper.fm/userguide/ReaperUserGuide668c.pdf), around page 222 talks about editing MIDI items. You can see a "piano roll" view that doesn't even require you to know the difference between quarter notes and eighth notes in music notation; instead, the notes are represented as rectangles of varying widths on a grid-like timeline. This grid *does* tell you where your beats and bars are, and you can arrange the notes among them. You can probably even "quantize" the notes (p. 168?) to be certain exact lengths (though I'm not sure it can handle 11/12ths). If these beats and bars don't seem to have anything to do with what you want, you might need to set the project's tempo ("bpm") to the speed you want; see p. 165.